# Edit RichTextBox programmatically without losing formatting

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have formatted text in the rtf file and I load it to my richTextBox. It works fine, but then I want to remove some text parts programmatically. If I do like that:

```
richTextBox.LoadFile("TextFile.rtf");
richTextBox.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(fromPosition, length);
```

text formatting disappears. I've tried to work with richTextBox.Lines, but there is no delete or edit function. All I need is to delete parts of loaded text without losing its formatting. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Paste RTF in RichTextBox but keep coloring and formatting (i.e: bold, underline, etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477676/c-paste-rtf-in-richtextbox-but-keep-coloring-and-formatting-i-e-bold-underl)

Comment: I've already read that post but still cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove text you first select it, programmatically by setting SelectionStart and -Length. Then you use the Cut Method:

```
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 20;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 120;
    richTextBox1.Cut();
```

If you want to avoid putting the removed text to the clipboard you can set it to `""` instead of 'cutting' it:

```
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = ""
```

Comment: Cut() should not be used here because it has the side effect of adding the removed text to the clipboard. Instead, you should use richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";

Answer (score 0):

Note that this only works when the RichTextBox's ReadOnly property is set to false.