# Collecting user input in different font styles

Tags: vb.net, text, fonts, user-input

My question is more of a fundamental question than an actual coding question, but is it possible to collect user input in different font styles. For instance, if a user were to copy and paste the following from another source into a text box on the form;

I ran to the car *and got a bag of chips.*

Is it possible to collect it so that each part of the string would retain its personal font?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, of course. .NET Framework provides [`RichTextBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).

`With the RichTextBox control, the user can enter and edit text. The control also provides more advanced formatting features than the standard TextBox control. Text can be assigned directly to the control, or can be loaded from a rich text format (RTF) or plain text file. The text within the control can be assigned character and paragraph formatting.`

I am sure there are other third party controls that can do same thing and better.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so the richtextbox will accept a copy and pasted sentence and keep it in that font or italicized? I have tried formatting it different ways and every time all the text is converted to a single base form instead of keeping some text italics and some not.

Comment: This question already has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477676/c-paste-rtf-in-richtextbox-but-keep-coloring-and-formatting-i-e-bold-underl